# Displaying a list of all *.java

Tags: grep, find

Display a list of all java files which name is `*.java` in your current working directory which contain the string *Example*, regardless of the case sensitivity of the latter's individuals letters.

Example file containing any instances of *example*, *EXAMPLE*, etc.

Comment: U&L is not a place for people to post their homework assignments and ask others to do their work for them... You should show us what you tried, at least... Not to mention that similar questions must have been answered here already...

Answer (score 1):

`grep -i example *.java`

Displays a list of files with the lines that match.

Comment: could use `-R` option too to search recursively, what do you think?

Comment: @tachomi Adding `-R` would search recursively in directories with names matching `*.java`. This assumes that they are directories with such silly names, and that they contain nothing but Java files (because every thing in those directories would be `grep`-ed).

Comment: Yeah, you can't use `-R` together with a glob pattern that you want matched on each file.  If you want to do that recursively, use `find`.

Answer (score 0):

POSIXly:

```
find . ! -name . -prune -type f -name '*.java' -exec grep -i example /dev/null {} +
```

Comment: Actually, I think `-not` is POSIX-compliant, while `!` isn't.  Some BSD `find(1)` require `!`, while GNU find supports both.

Comment: @lcd047: Can you give me the reference? http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html said that ! was defined by POSIX while -not wasn't.

Comment: Never mind.  There are contradictory claims in a few man pages, but  IEEE Std 1003.1-2008 actually requires `!`.  Sorry for the noise.